# How to insert same random value into two columns within one SQL Statement (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

My example doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO test_table 
 (column_1, column_2)
 VALUES (DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES(16), column_1);
```

I'm not interested in PL/SQL solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2)
  WITH x AS (SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES(16) as val FROM dual)
  SELECT val, val
  FROM x;
```

Thanks to Husqvik & Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use scalar subquery caching:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (column_1, column_2)
SELECT random, random FROM
    (SELECT (SELECT dbms_crypto.randombytes(16) FROM dual) random FROM dual);
```

Or using PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    random RAW(16) := dbms_crypto.randombytes(16);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test_table (column_1, column_2) VALUES (random, random);
END;
```

Comment: the sql statement doesn't work - inserts two different values.

Comment: PL/SQL works for sure. The first one relies on scalar-subquery caching. If it's not applied for any reason you get different values.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2)
  SELECT val, val
  FROM (SELECT DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES(16) as val FROM dual) x;
```

Or, this can be written as:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2)
  WITH x AS (SELECT DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES(16) as val FROM dual)
  SELECT val, val
  FROM x;
```

Comment: @trunkc . . . That seems very strange.  Try using `with`.

Comment: I get different values with WITH clause too. Only when the inline view is materialized either because it's used multiple times or using /*+ materialize */ hint I get same values.

Comment: Wow.  That really surprises me.  I don't see how Oracle would evaluate the expression twice.

Comment: It's pretty simple when you think in sets.

Comment: @Husqvik . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.  Oracle shouldn't be evaluating the single column in the subquery/CTE more than once, simply because of an additional reference to it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - this exactly is procedural thinking, trying to represent an operation using elemental steps. If you use a function in a query you don't know how many times it will be executed and you cannot rely on it. Changing of execution plan may result in different number of invocations. Even modifying the data may result into it.Typical example is the scalar subquery caching. Caching depends on distinct function parameter values and their order. If a hash collision occurs, cached value will not be used and function will be invoked. Another case is order of AND conditions with functions.

Comment: @Husqvik . . . The query defines a derived table with one column and one row.  I fail to see how allowing the engine to evaluate the value of the column multiple times has *anything* to do with procedural thinking.  This behavior suggests that Oracle is not correctly compiling queries with volatile function calls.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - this case is of course one of the simplest possible cases so people tend to have simple assumptions about it. But apparently you see that even in this case you cannot rely on it. The number of invocation of a function in a query is not deterministic. That is fact, it's by design. And it should always be taken into consideration. It's not related to compilation as the resolution if function is going to be invoked or not happens during actual execution.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temp table to store it?

```
set echo on
create table test_table (column_1 varchar2(100), column_2 varchar2(100));

create global temporary table rando_val (c1 varchar2(100));

insert
into    rando_val
values  ( dbms_crypto.randombytes(16) );

INSERT INTO test_table (column_1, column_2)
select  c1,
        c1
from    rando_val;

commit;

select  *
from    test_table;
```

Not all that elegant, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this weird query

```
select /*+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE  */  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(VAL1),UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(VAL2) from 
       xmltable('for $c in . return <r><val1>{$c}</val1><val2>{$c}</val2></r>'
                  passing (SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES(16)) as val FROM dual)
           columns
           "VAL1" varchar2(300) path '/r/val1',
            "VAL2" varchar2(300) path '/r/val2' )
```

If you want then don't covert varchar2 to raw again in last step. Mean this

```
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(VAL1)
```